# calculate sum of a column excluding comma in between a number in bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

This is the file(calculate.csv) which I have.

```
column1,column2,column3
10,'rohit', 123
20,'warner',-23
30,'anna',234
40,'shreya',19
50,'shravs',89
60,'vasu',12
100,'ajay',87
"1,000",'sumanth',-8
"2,000",'arjun',"1,228"
```

I need a command to calculate the sum of the column1

But it won't work for `"1,000"` and `"2,000"`.
Is there any other way to ignore comma between quotes `""`?

I need a sed command to ignore comma when it is in between "".
**Ex:- "1,000",'sumanth' it should become 1000,'sumanth'.**
The output should be 3310 for sum of column1.
The output should be 1761 for sum of column3.

Comment: what is your expected output, `3310` or `313`? and does your input has only one column, so to speak?

Comment: 3310 is my expected output for my input.

Comment: then please edit the question to add that detail... please make it clear that you need the sum of first column number, some of which could be inside double quotes with commas... also, can your input have numbers in columns other than the first? otherwise a simple `awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]/,""); sum += $0} END{print sum}'` will do

Comment: you need a delicated csv parser. check out `csv` module in python.

Comment: There are many columns which has numbers. I need sum of those columns.

Comment: Can't do this in bash scripting instead of python?

Comment: you need to realize this is a context free grammar(CFG). this grammar is more powerful than regular expression and hence cannot be parsed by it. there is no easy tool that i am aware of to do adhoc CFG parsing. use python and save your own time.

Comment: what i am gonna tell you extra is this csv format is so-called excel format, in which double quotes can escape almost all characters, including newlines. for example, if you have a cell `abc\ndef`, your line based parser will be extremely confused. again, do python and do yourself a favor.